# NDK r8c warning for asm objects regarding "Cortex-A8 erratum" - should I be worried?

Tags: assembly, android-ndk, arm, x264, cortex-a8

**Question:** What is the meaning of this warning? If there are no real-life consequences, I can live with it for a while... But I am concerned with what will happen if our program gets loaded on one of the faulty chips.

**Background:** With NDK r8c, linking of X264 encoder issues warnings:

```
cannot scan executable section 1 of libx264.a(dct-a.o) for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols
```

*... same warning for all assembly files in libx264.*

libx264.a itself was cross-compiled on the same machine with the same 4.6 toolchain taken from NDK.

Here are the instructions to easily reproduce the problem (Ubuntu or MacOS):

1. Download x264-snapshot-20121203-2245 from ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
2. Run `./configure --enable-pic --enable-strip --enable-static --cross-prefix=~/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=~/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --host=arm-linux`
3. Run `~/android-ndk-r8c/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/make`

It will build the static library, and after that display the Cortex-A8 warning while linking the x265 executable. I am not worried about the compiler warnings, because building libx264.a is done offline, it is not part of our official daily build.

I have reported this as http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40794.

I tried to add the [mapping symbols](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Mapping-Symbols.html) manually to `dct-a.S` following the [ARM.com instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0064d/BABCGAAH.html), but this had no effect.

Comment: That configure doesn't work for me. I get "No working C compiler found." I have the NDK at the right place. I just wonder if you have a  path problem for cross tool chain.

Comment: @auselen: no, I don't know what's wrong with your compiler path. What is your platform? I am afraid there is no easy way to configure on Windows. Maybe you have to follow the NDK instructions and prepare your standalone toolchain, which is not necessary on my Ubuntu machine. _Anyways, stay tuned: I have the answer!_

Comment: @auselen: on Mac OS, I found that **~** made the difference (and the coreect path, too). I ended up with `./configure --enable-pic --enable-strip --enable-static --cross-prefix=/Users/AlexCohn/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/Users/AlexCohn/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --host=arm-linux`

Comment: It was also ~ for me on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got THE answer from Andrew: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40794#c4

**tl;nr:** h264 makefile forcefully strips the mapping symbols. *I have double checked:* it is not my `--enable-strip` for `./configure` that makes this happen.

The quickest workaround is to run

```
make STRIP=
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix this for people who are not using VideoLan? I get the error above running ndk-build

Comment: @CoryTrese Can you elaborate?